# Extracting a key/tonality from a filename using

Tags: regex, max-msp-jitter

I'm trying to find a way to extract the key from the file name, bypassing all min/maj characters (case insensitive), but allowing # and b.

A couple of file name examples:

```
sample_F_one_shot.wav
sample_oneshot_F#maj.wav
sample_Ab_one_shot.wav
```

An example of what the result should look like:

```
A; B; C; D; E; F; G
```

and their combinations with `#` and `b`.

Here are the basic rules:

- The key is not case sensitive and can be written in small or capital letters.
- The key is not at the beginning of the file name.
- The key can be in brackets: "()"; "[]".
- There may be signs before the key: ""; ""; "."; " "; "space"; "-"; "--"; "*"; "-".
- After the key there may be signs: ""; ""; "."; " "; "space"; "-"; "--"; "*"; "-"; ".wav"; ",aif"; ".rx2".
- There cannot be letters before the key.
- There cannot be numbers before the key.
- After the key there may be numbers: “C1”; "F#2" - numbers must be cut off.
- Possible options with: "#maj"; "#Maj"; "#min"; "#Min"; "#m" - everything after "#" should be cut off

I came up with a 2 step system using [regexp]. In the first step I find the key with symbols around it, for example: `F; .F.; [F]; F#; _F#maj;` and so on...

Something like:

```
"regexp (?:[^a-gA-G#b]|^)([A-G](?:#|b)?(?:m(?:in(?:or)?)?|M(?:aj(?:or)?)?))(?:[^a-zA-Z#bd]|$)"
```

The second step is to simply get rid of all the characters, leaving only `#` and `b` in the key using another [regexp].

Problem: In the first step I am unable to achieve high accuracy in isolating the key with symbols.

Question: Perhaps there is an easier way to do this?

I think I'm confused about this. I also tried to do this using ChatGPT and it seems to be the best option I got, but it is not entirely accurate.

Comment: Try to describe the accepted input file names a little more precisely (what if the file name is "APRICOT.wav"? Should it be rejected? If not, what should the result be? What are the semicolons in your output?

Comment: I think you need to give more examples and, for each, the desired result.

Comment: Is it correct to assume that the _key_ is a single uppercase character, always preceded by an underscore and optionally followed by "b" or by a hash suffix ("#" + lowercase characters), and terminated either by another underscore (if in the middle of the file name) or by a dot (if located just before the file extension)?

Answer (score 0):

In the examples, the keys you want to extract appear to be surrounded by `_` or `.`. The keys have the form: A single `A`-`F` optionally followed by either `b` or `#` or `#maj`. You also mentioned 'min', so let's include that too.

A regexp for that would be:

```dart
final keyRE = RegExp(r"(?<=^|[_.])[A-F](?:b|#(?:maj|min)?)?(?=[_.]|$)");
```

That exactly follows the description above:

- Following a `_` or `.` (or start of input),
- A single `A`..`F`
- Optionally followed by either `b` or `#` or `#maj` or `#min`,
- Ended by another `.` or `_` (or the end of input).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample filenames and rules, you could use this regex with the case-insensitive flag (`i`):

```
(?<![A-Z0-9])[A-G][b#]?(?=(?:m(?:(?:aj|in)(?:or)?)?)?(?![A-Z]))
```

This matches:

- `(?<![A-Z0-9])` : lookbehind assertion for something which is not a letter or digit
- `[A-G]` : a character in the set `A` to `G`
- `[b#]?` : an optional `b` or `#`
- `(?=...)` : a positive lookahead assertion for:

  - `(?:m(?:(?:aj|in)(?:or)?)?)?` : an optional `m`, `maj`, `major`, `min` or `minor`
  - `(?![A-Z])` : something which is not a letter

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/exmGvZ/1)

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much where I started. But the difficulty is that there may be an example: [F]; (A#); F#maj. And spaces may be allowed before and after the key.

Comment: Could you please add some more examples to the question that demonstrate the other forms that can occur?

Comment: Sure! Here are the basic rules:

The key is not case sensitive and can be written in small or capital letters.
The key is not at the beginning of the file name.
The key can be in brackets: "()"; "[]".
There may be signs before the key: "_"; "__"; "."; " "; "space"; "-"; "--"; "*"; "_-_".
After the key there may be signs: "_"; "__"; "."; " "; "space"; "-"; "--"; "*"; "_-_"; ".wav"; ",aif"; ".rx2".

Comment: There cannot be letters before the key.
There cannot be numbers before the key.
After the key there may be numbers: “C1”; "F#2" - numbers must be cut off.
Possible options with: "#maj"; "#Maj"; "#min"; "#Min"; "#m" - everything after "#" should be cut off

Comment: @justewanproducer perhaps https://regex101.com/r/exmGvZ/1?

Comment: Nope :) For example for "Diginoiz_-_MVP4_OneShot_G#Maj_-_Bass" I get this "D G B" where "G" is the key, the “#” is also missing.

Comment: I just get `G#` https://regex101.com/r/exmGvZ/2

Comment: Note you need to add the `i` flag (case-insensitive) or change `[A-Z]` to `[A-Za-z]` in the two places it occurs in the regex

Comment: Oh, thank you so much Nick! Everything seems to be working fine, you are my hero!

Comment: @justewanproducer good to hear. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @justewanproducer you thank people by clicking the green checkmark at the upper-left of their answer.